# Trouble setting up PATH for Java on Debian

Tags: linux, debian, java, path, su

I am trying to get Oracle Java 7 update 3 working correctly on Debian 6. I have downloaded and set up the files in `/usr/java/jre1.7.0_03`. I have also set the following two lines at the end of `/etc/bash.bashrc`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jre1.7.0_03
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Logging in as other users and root is fine, Java can be found:

```
chris@mc:~$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_03"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_03-b04)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

However there are two cases where Java cannot be found as detailed below. Note that both of these worked fine when I have previously installed OpenJDK Java 6 via aptitude, but I need Oracle Java 7 for various reasons.

1. Most importantly, I cannot run commands as another user via `su`, despite the PATH showing that Java should be present. The user was created with `adduser chris`

   ```
   root@mc:~# su chris -c "echo $PATH"
   /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/java/jre1.7.0_03/bin:/bin
   root@mc:~# su chris -c "java -version"
   bash: java: command not found
   root@mc:~# su chris -c "/usr/java/jre1.7.0_03/bin/java -version"
   java version "1.7.0_03"
   ...
   ```

   How can it be in the `PATH` but not be found? *Update 05/04/2012: explained by Daniel, to do with it being a non-interactive shell so files such as `/etc/profile` and `/etc/bash.bashrc` are not executed.* Doing a full swap to that user and running Java works:

   ```
   root@mc:~# su chris
   chris@mc:/root$ java -version
   java version "1.7.0_03"
   ...
   ```
2. I run a script on start up which exhibits similar but slightly different problems. The script is located in `/etc/init.d/start-mystuff.sh` and calls a jar:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   # /etc/init.d/start-mystuff.sh
   java -jar /opt/Mars.jar
   ```

   I can confirm that the script runs on start up and the exit code is 127, which indicates command not found. Inserting a line to print/save the `PATH` shows that it is:

   ```
    /sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
   ```

   This second problem isn't as important because I can just point directly to the Java executable in the script, but I am still curious!

I have tried setting the full `PATH` and `JAVA_HOME` explicitly in `/etc/environment` which didn't help. I have also tried setting them in `/etc/profile` which doesn't seem to help either. I have tried logging in and out again after setting `PATH` in the various locations (duh!).

Anyway, long post for what will probably have a simple one line solution :( Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, I have spent far too long trying to fix it by myself.

*Motivation*

*The first problem may seem obscure but in my system I have users that are not allowed SSH access yet I still want to run processes as them. I have a ton of scripts operating in this way and don't want to have to change them all.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See: update-alternatives

Also:
Debian generally discourages developers *relying* on ENV variables, you have discovered one reason why.

Its not that they are taboo its just that they should not be expected to always be available.

Note:
Adding your java path at the end of the existing path means that any other java will be found, and used, first.

(i.e. the (symlink)  under /usr/bin )

so:

```
ls -lah /usr/bin/java
```

says:

> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Apr 22  2011 /usr/bin/java ->
>   /etc/alternatives/java

```
file $(which java)
```

> /usr/bin/java: symbolic link to `/etc/alternatives/java'

```
file /etc/alternatives/java
```

> /etc/alternatives/java: symbolic link to
>   `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/java'

**<side issue>
and also serves to demonstrate why $(exec in subshell style) is preferable, to 
"backtick exec mode" , or " eval this ".

(( as `` '' and ""  gets way too confusing, for me at least, 
and doesn't always work as expected in all shells all of the time.
 Investigate POSIX mode AKA /bin/sh ))

</side issue>**

`man update-alternatives`  explains why this alternative system exists ...

meantime

```
update-alternatives --config java
```

may help.

/usr/local/ is a good place to install source built packages...

There are also other ways to skin your cat.

Including:

- hand re-pointing the /usr/bin/java link :)

(though watch out for upgrades or dependency installs resetting it.. not a great choice but it works)

- setting an alias for java per user [1]
- prepending $PATH in the users .bashrc

(you can source .bashrc from .bash_profile if you like)

- calling the specific versions full path per instance

(safest bet but probably not practical)

[1]
.alias or .bashrc

```
help alias
```

(its a bash builtin)

Finally an example for good or ill:
taken from my Debian .bash_profile...

```
# include .bashrc if it exists

if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d ~/bin ] ; then
    PATH=~/bin:"${PATH}"
fi
```

**Hope this helps rather than hinders**

Pete

Comment: Hi Pete, I'll have a play around with update-alternatives; it does seem much better than messing with environment variables. Maybe I should have mentioned in my original post but I started from a minimal install of Debian with no version of Java on it. And I think everyone should be discouraged from relying on env variables, no matter what their system is ;) thanks!

Comment: @milkmansrevenge Cool. Good luck, It looks more complex than it is.

Comment: Yup, it turned out to be ridiculously simple. One line as predicted :) `update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java jre7u3 /usr/java/jre1.7.0_03/bin/java 5`. I also found another way to solve it using `$BASH_ENV` but update-alternatives is the best. I'll update my question so all of this is clear to any other visitors soon. Edit: Can't seem to tag you with `@`, guess my rating is too low.

Answer (score 1):

Many questions in one go, but:

**1.** You do

```
# su chris -c "echo $PATH"
```

This will substitute the variable `$PATH` before the command is run, which will give the `$PATH` for root. Try

```
# su chris -c "echo $HOME"
```

to see what I mean.

Instead, you can do

```
# su chris -c 'echo $PATH'
```

which will hinder the shell from expanding the variable in the first case, and instead actually get `chris`'s `$PATH`. You will most likely find that the changes have not permeated to that user.

Why not then? `/bin/sh` is linked to `/bin/dash` on Debian systems, and not `/bin/bash`. Dash won't read `/etc/bash.bashrc`. Perhaps you got Dash as default shell for the user `chris` when he was created. Look in `/etc/passwd` to see if this is the case.

Perhaps this clarifies question 2 as well.

---

**UPDATE:** Ah, `/etc/bash.bashrc` is only read for interactive shells. Read `man bash`, section "FILES". You don't start an interactive shell when you use `su` in that way.

---

**Update 2:** This example is one way:

```
# su chris -c 'myvar="hi there"; echo $myvar'
hi there
```

or similarly:

```
# su chris -c 'export myvar="hi there"; echo $myvar; export | grep myvar'
hi there
declare -x myvar="hi there"
```

(with `export`, the variable is available to spawned sub-processes as well, as usual).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise it was such a simple substitution when using `"` rather than `'`, however: `chris:x:1001:1001:,,,:/home/chris:/bin/bash` indicates that `/bin/bash` is the default shell for `chris` right?

Comment: Yes, it does indeed indicate that. However, read the updated section of my answer regarding interactive shells and start up files.

Comment: @milkmansrevenge: forgot to highlight your username so you'll get notified, and seem to have missed the edit time with an infinitesimal amount of time... Read my above comment.

Comment: thanks. I guess my question then simply becomes: How do I set the `$PATH` for non-interactive shells? The "FILES" section for `man bash` does hint that my solutions won't work. I'll have a search around for solutions and update my post if I find anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
sudo -u <user> -i
```

which will read `.bashrc` / `.bash_profile`.